# Remoting, serialization between services

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want to send a message to Actor, from a front-end API through a 3rd service, which has a directory of all actors.

Using Service Fabric Remoting with 2 parameters, the requested actor key and the main message, what will happen with serialization? Will the message be required to be deserialized and serialized again to be sent to actor?

Is it possible to avoid the serialization cost and redirect the main message to actor through the 3rd service?

Comment: You're going to have to serialize a message to communicate between any two services, be it binary or JSON, coming from within the cluster or outside. This can be tailored in V2 remoting (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting). Service remoting is very fast.

Comment: @KnowHoper, maybe it is not possible to be avoided, but fast is relevant to specific conditions. Especially if the front-end API awaits a response, the back and forth exchange's serialization cost will be double.